# Android - Crash when i have apostrophe in database and select data

Tags: android

I select data from my sqlite database. My problem is that when in database are apostrophes ("I' m John" - for example) and i try to select data, then my application crash.

If i don' t have apostrophes in database, then everything is all right.

My select data function:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + mainCollumn  + " WHERE used=0 " + " AND season <= " + seasons + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT " + count ;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            Question question = new Question(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                    cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),
                    Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(6)));

            questionList.add(question);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Going to need more info.  Do you have log or debugger outputs?

Comment: Using `?` and the `selectionArg` parameter will handle this problem: `db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {seasons})`. **Also** This is not necessary: `Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0))`, just use: `cursor.getInt(0)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specially handle apostrophes by replacing them with double apostrophes, but the best way is to use [`query()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) with `selectionArgs` instead of `rawQuery()`.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
String[] columns = new String[] {column1, column2}; // the columns you want
Cursor cursor = db.query(mainCollumn, String[] columns, "used=0 and season<=?", new String[] {seasons}, null, null, "RANDOM() LIMIT " + count);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue with any SQL as single quote (apostrophe) is the text delimiter character.  In your data, you must either replace apostrophe with another character or replace single apostrophes with double apostrophes.

```
Daniel O'Neil
```

becomes

```
Daniel O''Neil
```

[EDIT]
UgglyNoodles's recommendation is better.